# VBA - find a value, copy a single cell beneath this one & paste on a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a dataset in sheet1, and I need a VBA that will find a specific value in this dataset ("value123"), and then copy the cell directly beneath the cell that has been found (i.e. just one cell, not the whole column), and then paste it in A2 in sheet2.

I have been TRYING to use the offset feature but it's just not working..

```
Sub Find() 
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select 
    Set MyRng = Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) 
    For Each cell In MyRng 
        If cell.Value = "value123" Then 
            cell.Value = cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value 
        End If 
    Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: Your first cell is A1, you can't offset that by a negative there is no row 0

Comment: "not working" is not a very useful description of what happens when you run your code.  What does it do or not do that's different from what you want/expect?